# как сделать форму редактирования полей базы данных mysql через php

Tags: php, mysql

Есть поля которые динамический добавляются и при сохранении записываются в бд. После обновления страницы все поля пропадают(на странице). Как мне сделать форму для редактирования полей в базе данных через php. Сначала нужно как то получить эти таблицы, или как?
Вот мой код:
1)index.php

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="save_data.php">
        <input type="text" name="text_field[]">
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
    <button onclick="add_field()">ADD FIELD</button>
    <script>
        function add_field(){

            var x = document.getElementById("form");
            // создаем новое поле ввода
            var new_field = document.createElement("input");
            // установим для поля ввода тип данных 'text'
            new_field.setAttribute("type", "text");
            // установим имя для поля ввода
            new_field.setAttribute("name", "text_field[]");
            // определим место вствки нового поля ввода (перед каким элементом его вставить)
            var pos = x.childElementCount;

            // добавим поле ввода в форму
            x.insertBefore(new_field, x.childNodes[pos]);
        }
    </script>
```

2. save-data.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","customdynamycbutton");

$data = $_POST['text_field'];
$data = implode(",",$data);

$query = "INSERT INTO `teachers`(`name`) VALUES ('$data')";
if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)) {
    echo "Success: Все круто";
} else {
    echo "Error: не загрузилось";
}
?>
```

Вот скрин как они выглядят в бд:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQvQU.png

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то надо чтобы при загрузке страницы у тебя уже сразу отображалось не пустая страница, а прям все как в бд, так? Подгружались данные из этой самой бд? Если да то когда у тебя запускается страница, тебе нужно где то на `<input type="text" name="text_field[]">` сделать вместо него как то вот так: https://intop24.ru/article_15_lesson_4.php

Comment: @Gh0sTG0, спасибо за ответ. Да, нужно вывести данные из бд и что бы я мог эти данные отредактировать уже на сайте. Спасибо еще раз, сейчас попробую вывести данные из бд